# Keybinding conflicts occurred. They may interfere with normal accelerator operation

Tags: eclipse

When I open Eclipse, I have the following warning message:

[image]

The full message is as follows:

```
A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.python.pydev.analysis.actions.pyGlobalsBrowserWorkbench,Python Show Global Tokens (Global),
        Python Show Global Tokens (Global),
        Category(org.python.pydev.ui.category.source,PyDev - Editor,PyDev editor category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@6a54d849,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    com.python.pydev.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.python.pydev.editor.actions.pyShowBrowser,Python Show Global Tokens (Editor),
        Python Show Global Tokens (Editor),
        Category(org.python.pydev.ui.category.source,PyDev - Editor,PyDev editor category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@48a9b72d,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.python.pydev.ui.editor.scope,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@5bace7af,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

Despite removing the above-mentioned bindings as the following screenshot shows, and restarting Eclipse, I still get the same warning. Any idea what could explain this and how to get rid of this warning?

[image]

I hadn't added any bindings myself, but I had installed the [JSON Editor Eclipse Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-editor-plugin)  and [Json Tools Eclipse Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-tools) (I don't see why it would change those PyDev bindings though).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after a fresh installation of Eclipse IDE 2020-12. I did remove ALL conflicted key(s) as per the following:

In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys then scroll up/down and select the conflict key.  You can replace the Binding key(s) or Unbind the key(s) by clicking on the Unbind Command button then click on Apply and Close.

Note: You can delete your Workspace Log then Restart Eclipse. The Keybinding warning will not appear again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A have the same message although different conflict bindings. In my case Unbind Command resolved the issue.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2019-03-19 09:20:24.704
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2019-03-19 09:20:24.704
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
    Open a type in a Java editor,
    Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
    org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7108b12d,
    ,,true),null),
org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
    ,
    Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
    org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7a80b2e6,
    ,,true),null),
org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```